# how to require a minimum version of cocoapods?

Tags: cocoapods

Lately I've been using Xcode 8 Beta, and discovered that Cocoapods 1.1.beta.1 is necessary for what I need.

Some of my colleagues are on Cocoapods 1.0 and Cocoapods 1.0.1.

What I'd like to do is add a directive to the podfile, that requires that 1.1.beta.1 (at the minimum) should be used. If it's a lesser version of cocoapods, then "pod install" or "pod update" should fail.

I haven't seen any indication of this in the docs. But if it's there, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [cocoapods_version](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#cocoapods_version) field now.

Answer (score 0):

I think the official recommendation is to [use a Gemfile](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/a-gemfile.html).

It's a pain because you and your team have to start sticking `bundle exec` in front of everything, e.g. `bundle exec pod install`. And that's a pain because when you forget and just do e.g. `pod install` it'll *probably* work *most* of the time until it breaks spectacularly.

If you can cajole everyone into running `bundle exec pod install` then you're golden.

Bundler also makes it possible to, well, bundle CocoaPods and related build system dependencies into your repo. That would mean your colleagues (and the CI machine) don't have to update CocoaPods themselves. This comes at the cost of some repo churn whenever you bump the required CocoaPods version, but it could be worth it for a more consistent, less hassle build.